# at time of submit for review updated version getting error in " UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios9.1, xcode7.1

I uploaded new build in iTunes connect every thing is gone fine . now i am submitting  for review getting error.

**The app's Info.plist can't contain values for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key that would prevent this app from opening on any [?] device. For more information**,
What i can do now .